# understanding assignment inside condition solving precedence

Tags: php, loops, expression, variable-assignment

Today at work I got stucked in a line of code I can't achieve to understand.
I had a function in JavaScript that, to ensure getting an unique timestamp did that ugly loop:

```js
var ts = +new Date();
while (ts === (ts = +new Date()));
```

I think it's clear to understand that we're re-setting ts until it's value becomes different.

But when I tried to migrate the function to PHP code - like that:

```php
$ts = preg_replace('/^\d\.(\d+)\s(\d+)$/', '$2$1', microtime());
//regex extracts digits and re-positions them - ugly microtime :(
while ($ts === ($ts = preg_replace('/^\d\.(\d+)\s(\d+)$/', '$2$1', microtime())));
```

interpreter enters an infinite loop. All my tries seemed to point that $ts assignment is taking place before comparison, but I can't understand why left-side expression isn't being resolved first. My PHP knowns are not as big as my JavaScript ones, so I'm wondering if there is some key tip about PHP expressions and statements I'm leaking.

Advice: I don't want to fix my code by making a "well constructed" loop - the solution is obvious - I'd love to understand what's happening here. All help is much appreciated.

Comment: Here is some advice for you from a wise old man: "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it." -- Brian Kernighan

Comment: The solution may be obvious to you, but it isn't obvious to me, even though I've consider myself an above avarage programmer and have done so for the past 15 years. Also, if anyone in my team would come up with this, I'd tell them to rewrite it to a more readable construct.

Comment: Tanks Botond Balázs & GolezTrol. I'm very into good programming techiques - believe me when I say i use for example JSlint to build my JavaScript. This was only a quick test, but when I got stucked with that susprising issue, I couldn't stop thinking on that.

Comment: @Áxel: It is indeed a surprising (and very interesting) issue.

Comment: The more I read the "Operator Precedence" page the more I think I understand what the PHP guys wanted to transmit... I'm half divided between the key being the paragraph @GolezTrol named in his answer below or this one `Parentheses may be used to force precedence, if necessary.`. I'll try to do some tests tomorrow and force one of both options to demonstrate itself it's wrong, then consider the other the final explanation, and I'll come back with votes - your'e making this very difficult guys: none of you is giving a definitive answer but you're being incredibly helpful; thanks! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP needs the assignment to be evaluated first, before a comparison can be made. Normally, the assignment operator would have a very low precedence, so when you write `$a = $b + $c`, the addition is calculated first, before the result is assigned to $a. 
However, it is a special case, and although it doesn't seem to be documented very well, a similar case is found in the documentation, stating:

> Although `=` has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will
>   still allow expressions similar to the following: `if (!$a = foo())`, in
>   which case the return value of `foo()` is put into `$a`.

So in this case, PHP determines that it needs to do the assignment before it can negate the result of the assignment. I think a similar thing is happening here, although you're right that PHP should be able to do the assignment later.

Actually, the result might be unpredictable, as is the case with some other expressions:

```
// mixing ++ and + produces undefined behavior
$a = 1;
echo ++$a + $a++; // may print 4 or 5
```

Comment: Finally, you were right:
parentheses are not the cause:

`while (($ts) === ($ts = preg_replace('/^\d\.(\d+)\s(\d+)$/', '$2$1', microtime())));`

keeps looping; even

`while (($ts) === $ts = preg_replace('/^\d\.(\d+)\s(\d+)$/', '$2$1', microtime()));`

keeps looping, but silly

`while (($ts = $ts) === ($ts = preg_replace('/^\d\.(\d+)\s(\d+)$/', '$2$1', microtime())))`

yep works!

Answer (score 1):

PHP will evaluate the assignment before the comparison, so by the time it does `$ts ===`, `$ts =` has already happened. Here's a quick fix:

```
$ts = preg_replace('/^\d\.(\d+)\s(\d+)$/', '$2$1', microtime());

//regex extracts digits and re-positions them - ugly microtime :(
while ($ts === ($ts2 = preg_replace('/^\d\.(\d+)\s(\d+)$/', '$2$1', microtime()))) {
    $ts = $ts2;
}
```

Also, PHP has a handy function called uniqid() that will do something similar for you. It will give you a unique string every time.

Comment: I already know it works that way, i've suffereed it for nearly an hour ;)
What i'd love to know is why, any reference in the php documents that explains the evaluation precedence in that case or something like that.

By the way, many thanks for uniquid()

Comment: It indeed evaluates the assignment first. The order of expression doesn't influence that in any way. If you write `while (($ts = ...) === $ts)` the script also hangs.

Comment: PHP is **so** weird. I don't want to know what kind of a horrible mess the codebase must be to have such strange issues.